# Using cursor in order to fulfill a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

this is my scenario:
I have a table Employees where I need only to consider one attribute (salary) all the others are not needed in order to do the exercise. I have to create another table (least_earners) and insert inside this table the last n (inputed from user) earners from employees.

I have done this, but I would like to know if is ok or if I have made mistakes (I am working with Oracle DB and PL/SQL). It is possible to create a table without creating before an object? Does it work like the normal creation with SQL?

```
DECLARE
 bottom_n_salaries 
   NUMBER := &bottom_salaries;
 CURSOR emp_cursor IS
   SELECT DISTINCT salary 
   FROM employees
   ORDER BY salary ASC;
 CREATE TYPE least_earners_obj 
   AS OBJECT (salary NUMBER(8));
 CREATE TYPE least_earners 
   AS TABLE OF least_earners_obj;
BEGIN
 OPEN emp_cursor;
   LOOP
     INSERT INTO least_earners 
     VALUE(FETCH emp_cursor);
   EXIT WHEN emp_cursor%ROWCOUNT >bottom_n_salaries
   OR emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;
 CLOSE emp_cursor;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PL/SQL to do this, though you can use it. You can use `CREATE table AS ...`:

```
CREATE TABLE least_earners AS
  SELECT sal FROM (
    SELECT sal
    FROM employees
    ORDER BY sal)
  WHERE ROWNUM <= &bottom_salaries
```

Or if the table already exists you can use `INSERT INTO table SELECT ...`:

```
INSERT INTO least_earners (sal)
  SELECT sal FROM (
    SELECT sal
    FROM employees
    ORDER BY sal)
  WHERE ROWNUM <= &bottom_salaries
```

If your assignment requires PL/SQL, there are some errors in your code above (*addendum: I based this on the INSERT ... FETCH but I could be wrong*), plus it's far too complicated for the task at hand unless you're required to use objects.

---

**Addendum** PL/SQL with a cursor is a requirement, so adjusted the answer accordingly...

First a couple points:

- I don't think `INSERT INTO least_earners VALUE(FETCH emp_cursor)` is valid syntax but I'm not at a place where I can test it. The example below doesn't use it.
- You're inserting into the other table and checking `%NOTFOUND` *afterwards*. You need to do it before.

Overall something like this should do, but as I mentioned above I'm not in a place where I can test it. Tweakage may be needed:

```
DECLARE
 bottom_n_salaries NUMBER := &bottom_salaries;
 thisSalary NUMBER;
 CURSOR emp_cursor IS
   SELECT DISTINCT salary 
   FROM employees
   ORDER BY salary ASC;
BEGIN
 OPEN emp_cursor;
   LOOP
     FETCH emp_cursor INTO thisSalary;
     EXIT WHEN emp_cursor%ROWCOUNT > bottom_n_salaries
            OR emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
     INSERT INTO least_earners VALUES (thisSalary);
   END LOOP;
 CLOSE emp_cursor;
END;
```

If moving the `EXIT WHEN` messes up your "bottom salary" logic, you can go to two `EXIT` tries:

```
     ...
     EXIT WHEN emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
     INSERT INTO least_earners VALUES (thisSalary);
     EXIT WHEN emp_cursor%ROWCOUNT > bottom_n_salaries;
     ...
```

Comment: Hello Ed! thank you for your answer :D Yes I need to use PL/SQL block and a cursor in order to do the task; object actually are not required but I used it because I am sure that it could be translated in a table in the DECLARE part... I am not sure if a can simply declare a CREATE TABLE instead..

Comment: @user2179694 - you cannot use DDL commands as CREATE TYPE etc... in PL/SQL.

Comment: so is it right my approach to create an object and after create a table from that object?

Comment: Yes, but (a) @Art is right that you can't do it in PL/SQL, and (b) you don't really need to. You just care about the salary as far as variables go, and you only care about it for one row at a time so there's no need for a `TABLE OF`. I'll update my answer shortly with PL/SQL.

Comment: Ok Ed thank you! :D the problem is that I need a table (is the assignment that requires it) Although it could be written in a simpler way! :)

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer. It should get you a little closer. Basically you're doing one row and one value, so a scalar variable makes more sense than an `OBJECT` and a `TABLE OF OBJECT` type. You'll find in the industry that DBA's don't like to create *anything* without a good reason, and the worst thing about that is they're usually right :)

Comment: As for the "need a table" - I'm not 100% sure what you mean. Are you required to create the table within the PL/SQL procedure? That's pretty advanced, at least conceptually. Is it good enough to create it before running the procedure?

Comment: Ed I really thank you for your time :D. Yes in the assignment I need to create it :-/ I think it should be fine to create it outside, but I think since is pretty easy to create a table from an object it should be the right approach? what do you think?

Comment: Do you have a working example of creating tables from objects? It's not something I'm familiar with. Even assuming you can create a table from an object, I doubt Oracle would let you do it in PL/SQL - it flat out doesn't allow DDL commands in PL/SQL. There's a workaround, but (a) it's brutal and (b) it'll take you outside the scope of your assignment - waaaay outside :)